# Use case diagram for pizza app

Tags: use-case

Here is a hand drawn use case diagram for a pizza app. My friend wants to add a Credit Payment Agent (circled in red) and connect it to an included use case, which is Authorize Credit Card Use, as depicted in the image. From my understanding, included use cases such as Authorize Credit Card Use are not executed on its own, therefore actors do not directly interact with them. Is this right? If so, then we have no use for the actor Credit Payment Agents? Also, what other actors and/or use cases do you think I should consider adding?

[use case for pizza app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lofzf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying here is a functional decomposition. Use cases are synthesized.

You are misusing the use case diagram where you should actually use an activity diagram.